# How to select the data from MySQL table only one record if there are same multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have MySQL table with categories and sub-categories i want that in table

category is Sales and sub-category is English like this again there is record for Sales and sub-Category Chinese so there are 4 categories with sub categories so i want that it should select the categories from table but if there are 4 records for category Sales while selecting category it just show for 1 for category.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * category FROM catalog_Master");
```

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: Just a Comment... mysql_query is now deprecated, remember that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the query will be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM catalog_Master");
```